# Picture control in QT

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian, picturebox

i am learning QT, i am not getting how to get the picture control in QT?.
in .net we have picture control right same way i need in QT.
i know text edit support pictures but is there any alternatives.
please tell if so.

Thanks

Comment: it means,
simple control which just display pictures,
in .net we have picture control its job is just to show images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you mean a control for showing pictures. In that case, simply use a [QLabel](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qlabel.html#details) and call [setPixmap](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qlabel.html#pixmap-prop). There is a more versatile, but less polished [picture widget here](http://qt4.digitalfanatics.org/articles/zoomer.html).